# How do you make a Google Docs Form public?

Tags: google-drive

I have a Google Docs form that when I try to access while not logged in it asks me to log in. I'm trying to access the URL of the "live form". It's not working.

I've tried removing the domain information from the URL, but that doesn't work.

How do I make a Google Docs form public?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm brain-dead! There is a check box "Require login to access form" on the form editor. I just had to un-check this.

Comment: You might (or might not) be brain dead but I'm glad you asked the question because I had the same problem !

Comment: The checkbox label has apparently changed to "Only allow one response per person" and a tool-tip says that "Respondents must have a Google account".